# How let the Json.net return a new T value when the Deserialize Object is null?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

when I'm use the Json.net, I always meet some problem like that:

```
 List<Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(personsJson);
```

You guys know: Some time because the server error or any other problem, the return json string just a **null value**.

but When the **personsJson** is a **null** value. the Json.net will throw:**System.ArgumentNullException**

I just need it auto give me a new source object, I mean when the personsJson is **null**, jut gime me back: **new List of Person()**; that will be more helpfull, I don't need determine every json string before descrialize one by one.

I thought there is maybe has some setting can do this, but not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So why not just check for *null*?

```
List<Person> persons = personsJson != null 
                        ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(personsJson)
                        : new List<Person>();
```

If you have too many codes like this, you can generalize it:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this string json) where T : new()
{
     return json != null 
                    ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)
                    : new T();
}


List<Person> persons = personsJson.Deserialize<List<Person>>();
```

Comment: Use extension method is a good idea. that's a safe descrialize now. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the variable before trying to deserialize it:

```
public List<Person> DeserializePersons(string personsJson)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(personsJson))
    {
        return new List<Person>();
    }
    else
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(personsJson);
    }
}
```

However, you may want to handle a "no persons found" case different from "an error occurred while retrieving persons".